# MyAdapter setItemClickListener

Tags: android

I need to navigate to another activity in this myadapter class. Can someone show me how to replace that toast to navigate to another activity? Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

Context c;
ArrayList<Movie> movies;
LayoutInflater inflater;

ArrayList<Movie> filterList;
CustomFilter filter;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
    this.c = c;
    this.movies = movies;
    this.filterList=movies;
}

//TOTLA NUM OF MOVIES


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(inflater==null)
    {
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    //PERFORM INFLATION
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.model,null);
    }

    //BIND DATA TO VIEWS
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(convertView);
    holder.nameTxt.setText(movies.get(position).getName());
    holder.img.setImageResource(movies.get(position).getImage());

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(c,movies.get(position).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //RETURN A ROW
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if(filter==null)
    {
        filter=new CustomFilter(filterList,this);
    }

    return filter;
}
```

Comment: i tried that but still got errors

Answer (score 0):

**It works for me**

Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);

Comment: got no errors but doesnt navigate to another activity

Comment: Intent intnt=new Intent(MainActivity.this,newactivity.class); 
                          startActivity(intnt);                                                               //Use this to call your intent         startActivity(intnt);

Comment: the propblem is that im filtering it but insted of giving correct activity after filtering..it gives me the case 0 activity